# QML - how to overlay a label

Tags: qml, label, overlay

I would like to create a progress bar in which the progress is also displayed as text.

Through a blog post, the progress bar was quickly created.

[image]

Unfortunately, the progress bar overwrites the text. Is there a way to overlay this?

[image]

```
Item {
  id: item
  property double maximum: 10
  property double value: 50 //mill.value
  property double minimum: 0
  property bool visibleValue: true
  height: parent.height
  width: parent.width

Rectangle { id: frame; width: parent.width; height: parent.height; color: "lightgrey"; border.width: 1; radius: 0.5 * height
    Label { 
        anchors.centerIn: parent; 
        text: item.value + " %"; 
        color: "black"; 
        font.bold: true; 
        visible: item.visibleValue 
    }
    Rectangle { 
        visible: item.value > item.minimum
        x: 0.1 * frame.height;  y: 0.1 * frame.height
        height: 0.8 * frame.height
        width: Math.max(height, Math.min((item.value - item.minimum) / (item.maximum - item.minimum) * (parent.width - 0.2 * frame.height), parent.width - 0.2 * frame.height)) // clip
        color: 'darkgrey'
        radius: parent.radius
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What blog post creates such a well thought out progress bar with such a flaw?

Comment: I have added the label part and so the error is on me. Swapping rectangle and label works fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the order of the inner `Label` and `Rectangle`.

There are other issues, such as the display of the label being incorrect for your example. You will get "2%" shown, when, in fact, for a range of 0-10 and a value of 2, the calculated percentage should be "20%". I thought I just draw that to your attention, but, I haven't applied the fix, since, I am not sure what you're gunning for.

```
Item {
    id: item
    property double maximum: 10
    property double value: 2 //mill.value
    property double minimum: 0
    property bool visibleValue: true
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    
    Rectangle { id: frame; width: parent.width; height: parent.height; color: "lightgrey"; border.width: 1; radius: 0.5 * height
        Rectangle { 
            visible: item.value > item.minimum
            x: 0.1 * frame.height;  y: 0.1 * frame.height
            height: 0.8 * frame.height
            width: Math.max(height, Math.min((item.value - item.minimum) / (item.maximum - item.minimum) * (parent.width - 0.2 * frame.height), parent.width - 0.2 * frame.height)) // clip
            color: 'darkgrey'
            radius: parent.radius
        }
        Label { 
            anchors.centerIn: parent; 
            text: item.value + " %"; 
            color: "black"; 
            font.bold: true; 
            visible: item.visibleValue 
        }
    }
}
```